# No interpreters available in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have just installed the following on my Mac (Yosemite 10.10.3):

- oracle java 1.8 update 45
- scala 2.11.6
- spark 1.4 (precompiled release: http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz)
- zeppelin from source (https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin)
  no additional config, just copied created zeppelin-env.sh and zeppelin-site.xml from templates. no edits.

I Followed the installation guidelines: https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/install/install.html

I have build zeppelin without problems:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Started it

```
./bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

Opened http://localhost:8080 and opened the Tutorial Notebook.
Here is what happens when I refresh the snippets:

[image: md interpreter]
[image: sh interpreter, note that the interpreter name shows as 'null']
[image: sql interpreter]

Here is the exception for the md interpreter in the webapp logs:

```
ERROR [2015-06-19 11:44:37,410] ({WebSocketWorker-8} NotebookServer.java[runParagraph]:534) - Exception from run
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: **Interpreter md not found**
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Note.run(Note.java:269)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer.runParagraph(NotebookServer.java:531)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer.onMessage(NotebookServer.java:119)
    at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer.onWebsocketMessage(WebSocketServer.java:469)
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decodeFrames(WebSocketImpl.java:368)
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decode(WebSocketImpl.java:157)
    at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer$WebSocketWorker.run(WebSocketServer.java:657)
```

Restarting the interpreter doesn't seem to cause errors.

Comment: I was having the same problem and resolved it based on your answer. However I didn't see a stacktrace after error. Did you do something to enable stacktrace on zepeline ui?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok I have just found the answer, at the top of the tutorial there is a snippet about interpreter binding, click the **save** button and all start to work normally.

Comment: thanks for the soln. I had same problem. however how did you enable stacktrace on zepeline ui? I just saw ERROR in top right of paragraph with no stack trace in report section.

Comment: Clicking the _save_ button yields me precisely the same error again. I'm using the docker variant of the tutorial mentioned in the tutorial page (http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html).

Comment: @Samuel Kerrien Can this be set up on window 8 r2 machine?

Comment: @Samuel Kerrien Any help on this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312233/zeppeling-throwing-nullpointerexception-while-configuring

Comment: @Samuel Kerrien  I tried 0.8.0 versioin got errors .. then i tried with 0.7.0 version...I am not able to create spark notebook. it dispaly the name of the notebook but i am not able to open it by clicking , if i right click and open in other tab/window it displays empty notebook ...how to fix it ...any help please?

Comment: @Shyam No idea about windows but there are tutorials covering that for Windows 10, maybe that would help: https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/