# Apache zeppelin - enable stacktrace

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I installed "Binary package with all interpreters: zeppelin-0.6.1-bin-all.tgz" from download site. While trying out tutorial notebook I was missing `md` interpreter as I didn't select and save all interpreters. I saw error `Interpreter md not found` but didn't see any further stacktrace. I noticed that some people are seeing it. [No interpreters available in Zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935534/no-interpreters-available-in-zeppelin)
PS - I do see stacktrace in logs/zeppelin.local.log in install dir but I don't see it in UI