# Zeppeling throwing NullPointerException while configuring

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to set up zeppelin-0.8.0 on my windos 8 r2 OS. I have already running spark on my console i.e. SPARK_HOME and JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME set up and running fine. But while I am trying to execute printl("hello") in zeppelin spark interpreter it is throwing bellow error ...
I already set  SPARK_HOME and JAVA_HOME in zeppelin-env.cmd file.

Error

```
DEBUG [2019-01-22 10:05:34,129] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[start]:153) - callbackServer is serving now
 INFO [2019-01-22 10:05:34,143] ({pool-2-thread-2} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[start]:190) - Run interpreter process [C:\Software\Zepplin\zepplin\bin\interpreter.cmd, -d, C:\Software\Zepplin\zepplin/interpreter/spark, -c, 10.188.16
DEBUG [2019-01-22 10:05:34,419] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) - When was unexpected at this time.
 INFO [2019-01-22 10:05:34,435] ({Exec Default Executor} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[onProcessFailed]:250) - Interpreter process failed {}
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 255 (Exit value: 255)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.access$200(DefaultExecutor.java:48)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor$1.run(DefaultExecutor.java:200)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR [2019-01-22 10:06:34,177] ({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:190) - Job failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: When was unexpected at this time.

        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:205)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:64)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(RemoteInterpreter.java:111)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:164)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:132)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:407)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR [2019-01-22 10:06:52,103] ({pool-2-thread-2} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2294) - Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: When was unexpected at this time.

        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:205)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:64)
```

Comment: Also share interpreter log. This just shows error starting a remote interpreter process. Zeppelin just indicates that remote process hasn't started which is just a symptom. Actual problem's error is in a separate log file.

Comment: @Tagar can you help me , what am i doing wrong here

Comment: From information you provided we can't tell what's wrong. You also need to share interpreter log (real problem is there), not just zeppelin server log.

Comment: I am afraid zeppelin 0.8.0 doesn't support windows

Comment: ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) - When was unexpected at this time.
({Exec Default Executor} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[onProcessFailed]:250) - Interpreter process failed {}
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 255 (Exit value: 255)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:190) - Job failed

Comment: ({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:190) - Job failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: When was unexpected at this time.
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:205)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)

Comment: @Tagar thank you but how can I get interpreter log ?

Comment: @zjffdu huu then which version support windows ?

Comment: @Jary zhen any help is appreciated.

Comment: Go through this.. https://gist.github.com/codspire/7b0955b9e67fe73f6118dad9539cbaa2

printing hello world does throw an error. Check if you are able to get sc.version

Comment: @VishalR Sorry Vishal , no luck ... one more thing I am working scala with spark 2.3.1 , do I still need pyspark ? Why do I need ?

Comment: @Tagar  Unfortunately even if Enable the logs , I dont see any logs in the log file , not sure how to capture the logs